# MSBuild task to get update FileAssemblyVersion for only projects with changes

Tags: c#, msbuild, assemblies, msbuild-task

Is there any way, using msbuild or otherwise, to detect which projects have changes in the current build and update the FileAssemblyVersion attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs for those projects only?

Comment: Your question has very little to do with MSBuild, what you are actually asking is "How do I programmatically identify the set of changes in a period" which is completely dependent on your source control server, so no one can answer this without knowing what source control system you want to query this info from.

Comment: I am using TFS 2008.  My pie in the sky thought would be something along these lines:
Before I call the target that does the compile of the sln's, I call an MSBuild custom task that update the FileAssemblyVersion for any projects that have files which changed, which in turn triggered the current build.  Obviously, we are talking about a continuous integration setting here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've set up incremental [get and] compiles, the next step would be to hook into the MSBuild sequence. Have a look in `FrameworkDir\Microsoft.Common.Targets`. The problem is that things just are not set up to work in this way - the fact that there are `_TimestampBeforeCompile` and `_TimeStampAfterCompile` steps which just show that you cant determine a priori if something is going to compile. While you could theoretically hook in before [the language specific] CoreCompile [e.g., in Microsoft.CSharp.targets], the problem would be that you need to have the same `Inputs` as it does in order to determine if its going to happen, which would mean lots of cut and pasting and keeping in sync with system files. The other thing to be wary of is noted in the comment at the top of the `_ComputeNonExistentFileProperty` target.

So, outside of doing some very deep modifications to the sequence (e.g., hooking in a 'post build' bit which forces a second compile if a custom `_TimeStampAfterCompile` of yours detects that a compilation took place, I'd say there's no easy, recommended or supported way.

Having said that, the `AssemblyFileVersion` (you refer to `FileAssemblyVersion`, which doesnt exist :P) is easy to modify after the compile as its just a resource - you'll find tools for that. But I assume you're really talking about doing both it and the `AssemblyVersion`, which cant be tweaked after the fact in the same way.